# Form the PDE by eliminating arbitrary function

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$\phi(x+y+z, x^2+y^2-z^2)=0$$
Here x and y are independent variables and z=f(x,y).

I am solving it in following manner:

Let $u=x+y+z$ and $v=x^2+y^2-z^2$

$\implies \phi(u,v)=0$

Partially differentiation $\phi$ w.r.t x
$\implies \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial u}(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial v}(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})=0$

Here I have confusion if $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1$ or $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$

Comment: If you don't specify what kind of PDE they are an infinity of different answer to your question. One can suppose that you are looking for a first order linear PDE. Right or not ? Please re-edit your question without  ambiguity and show where you are stuck.

Comment: @JJacquelin edited the question to the point where I am stuck. According to the source I am referring to $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1$. So what will be the correct value of $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1$ ,as here $x,y,z$ are just given to be the parameters of a arbitary function,not in the usual sense of function with two variable plotted in $\mathbb{R}^3$.,where $z=f(x,y)$

Comment: @NewBornMATH Why not $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=1+\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ (because z is not an independent variable)?

Comment: I have edited my comment a bit that should be enough.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that x and y are independent variables and z is dependent variable i.e. z=f(x,y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoping that the approach below is more understandable :

Suppose that the sought PDE be of the first order linear kind, that is :
$$A(x,y,z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+B(x,y,z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=C(x,y,z) \tag 1$$
or equivalently :
$$a(x,y,z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+b(x,y,z)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1 \tag 2$$
with $a=\frac{A}{C}$ and $b=\frac{B}{C}$ .
The goal is to determine the functions  $a(x,y,z)$ and $b(x,y,z)$ so that the general solution of Eq.$(2)$ be on the form of implicit equation :
$$\phi(x+y+z\:,\:x^2+y^2-z^2)=0 \tag 3$$
Thus the equations of characteristic curves are :
$$x+y+z=c_1 \tag 4$$
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=c_2 \tag 5$$
Eq.$(2)$ can be solved thanks to the characteristic method. The system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dx}{a(x,y,z)}=\frac{dy}{b(x,y,z)}=\frac{dz}{1} \tag 6$$
Applying the wellknown properties of fractions :
$$\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{dx+dy+dz}{a+b+1}\tag 7$$
$$\frac{dx}{a}=\frac{dy}{b}=\frac{dz}{1}=\frac{xdx+ydy-zdz}{xa+yb-z} \tag 8$$
From Eqs.$(4)$ and $(5)$, on the characteristic curves :
$$dx+dy+dz=0 \tag 9$$
$$xdx+ydy-zdz=0 \tag {10}$$
Putting $(9)$ into $(7)$ and $(10)$ into $(8)$ implies :
$$\begin{cases}
a+b+1=0 \\
xa+yb-z=0
\end{cases}\tag {11}$$
This system $(11)$ of equations can be solved for $a$ and $b$ :
$$\begin{cases}
a=\frac{z+y}{x-y} \\
b=-\frac{z+x}{x-y}
\end{cases}\tag {12}$$
Bringing them back into Eq.$(2)$ :
$$\frac{z+y}{x-y}\:\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-\frac{z+x}{x-y}\:\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=1$$
A convenient PDE is :
$$\boxed{(z+y)\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}-(z+x)\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=(x-y)}$$
which general solution is : $\quad\phi(x+y+z\:,\:x^2+y^2-z^2)=0 $ .